# Entity Framework Core - Best practices for generic table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a .NET Core application and looking for some advice on best EF core practices.

At the moment, I have an entity (`Entity1`) that can have 1 or many of Entity2

Entity2 is a simple table, with an ID and 2 Col fields

```
ID    Col1    Col2
------------------
1     Val1    Val2
2     Val3    Val4
```

I now have a new entity (`Entity3`) and would like to use `Entity2` table also as it requires the same two columns.

So, I'd like to extend Entity2 where it has a `SourceType` (`Entity1`, `Entity3` etc) and the `EntityID`. There entity can have one or more values in table. See below for a sample

```
ID    Col1    Col2     SourceType  SourceID
-------------------------------------------
 1    Val1    Val2       Ent1         1  
 2    Val3    Val4       Ent1         1
 3    Val44   Val55      Ent3         1
 4    Val66   Val77      Ent3         2
 5    Val35   Val46      Ent1         2
```

Is the best practice how to do this using Entity Framework Core?

Comment: What is your sourcetype and sourceid?Do they have relationship with Entity1?

Comment: SourceType would be the different Entity types (Entity 1, Entity 3) and the Source ID is the id of the entity item